# Weird behavior in setting navigation item background and title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am working on a simple iphone app. I am attempting to style it by setting an image for the navigation item bar.  using this code

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Test";
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

First, must I have the title of my view show up but, once i load the picture it covers this title.  So, how can I make it so that my title (test in this case) will be untop my image.

But my biggest issue is that, why does my navbar image show like how it does in image B, why is the back button pushing the image to the side. ( it is the same image) Would like if I could be told how to correct this.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code and it should fix your problem.

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks but seemed to have" pushed" my view down a bit, i cant see items(in simulator) at the very bottom of my view but i can see them in the storyboard

Comment: If you make the navigation bar not translucent (or setting a background image, I can't remember) it changes how views respond the the top layout guide. Make sure your constraints are set properly in storyboard.

Comment: @DBoyer ok thank you. I have no constraints yet, like i said, i just dont see objects that was on the very bottom of my view. but no problem if I cannot change that